# How do I compare two SQL queries to run on Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, benchmarking

I need to compare two queries that will run in my Postgres database.

How do I know the execution time and any other statistics of them so I can produce a reliable benchmark between them?

Comment: You use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`  https://thoughtbot.com/blog/reading-an-explain-analyze-query-plan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two interesting data points to collect and compare:

1. The execution time.

   For that, simply execute the query using `psql` connected via UNIX sockets (to factor out the network) and use `psql`'s `\timing` command to measure the execution time as seen on the client.

   Do not use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` for that since that would add notable overhead which affects your measurements.

   Make sure to run the query several times to get a reliable number. That number will correspond to the execution time with a warm cache.

   If you want to measure execution time with a cold cache, restart PostgreSQL **and empty the file system cache**.
2. The number of blocks touched by the query.

   For that, run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` once for each query.

   The number of blocks touched is significant for performance: the fewer blocks a query touches, the faster it will (often) be. This number is particularly significant for performance with a cold cache; the fewer blocks, the less execution time will depend on caching.